# Factor equation?

Tags: prime-numbers, systems-of-equations, factoring, cryptography

For semi-prime `c`, is there an equation or system of equations that will find its factors?

In other words, if a prime number `a` time a prime number `b` equals semi-prime `c`, where `c` isn't one and neither `a` nor `b` are equal to one, how can I find a or b in terms of c?

In math notation, `ab = c {a && b ∈ prime: c ∈ semi-prime}`.

I attempted to solve it by making the observation that, since `ab =  c`, `b = c/a`. This meant that we could do a substitution and find that `(a^2)/c = c`. The issue with this is it follows that `a^2 = c^2`, and therefore `a = ±c` and `b = ±1`, which is not valid as both `a` and `b` must be prime numbers.

Then I tried some other *almost-valid* proofs (meaning proofs that make unwarrented leaps in logic that are only sometimes accurate), that while interesting, don't add anything here because they only work if `c` is *also* a perfect square, and prove that `a = b` so `a^2 = c` which means that `a = b = sqrt(c)`, which is only valid some of the time.

Finally, I tried doing some "dancing with substitution" stuff that just kept going in circles.

Is this problem just impossible, or is there a solution?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Nobody knows a *fast* algorithm to do this.  If one exists, it will break the RSA cryptosystem.

Comment: @AnotherUser I will not again trade appeal for concision. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Dan do you know *why* such a thing is impossible?

Comment: @HeneryJohnson: It's never been *proven* impossible; it's just that nobody's ever found a way to do it, despite the problem being well-known and financially valuable.

Comment: Concerning RSA , it is even worse. It could not be proven that it is safe if the enemy cannot factor the public number. Why RSA is neverthelessed used ? This is another question, apparently people trust that it is safe.

Comment: The Shor algorithm never convinced me , but should it work , then the existence of a quantum computer (it is even occasinally claimed that they already exist!) would of course make RSA completely useless unless we would use so large primes that it will be difficult to find them at all.

Comment: The ever increasing computational power is anyway a danger for RSA , I am not an expert what is currently secure (how much digits we need) and noone knows what will be secure in $50$ years.

Comment: Pollard-rho algorithm works in O(c^1/4) if it is guaranteed that c is the product of two primes. It’s not the fastest, but it doesn’t need any deep maths at all, so yo can read it and actually understand it. Should be good enough for 160 bit numbers with your home computer.

Comment: Peter I vaguely remember that being able to decode  RSA encrypted data (without factoring) leads to a factoring algorithm for the public key. So they would be equivalent.